# Выполнение функции только если найден элемент на странице

Tags: javascript, html

Есть основной код который должен выполняться

```
   var realInner = document.getElementById("real-inner").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("fake-inner").innerHTML = realInner;
```

Но он должен выполняться, если на странице найден элемент `.real-inner`. Для это нахожу элементы и выполняю метод `forEach`. Получается следующая конструкция:

```
 document.querySelectorAll(".real-inner").forEach (function() {
   var realInner = document.getElementById("real-inner").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("fake-inner").innerHTML = realInner;
 });
```

Функция не выполняется, но и не выдает ошибки. Если вызвать `console.log(realInner)` то получаю `Uncaught ReferenceError: realInner is not defined at <anonymous>:1:13`

Подскажите в какую сторону копать решение?

Comment: Селектор `.real-inner` ищет по классу. А у вас элемент с таким id. Измените селектор на `#real-inner`.

Comment: не совсем так, для поиска по Ид есть `getElementById('id')`, и форича там никакого не нужно, так как Ид повторяться не должни !

Comment: Да, у меня тут две ошибки: логическая и орфографическая. Все спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решение

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  //Автозаполнение текста #fake-inner на странице project
  let innerSwitcher = function () {

    // Определяем переменные
    let real = document.getElementById("real-inner"),
        fake = document.getElementById("fake-inner");

    // Условие для выполнение скрипта
    if (!real || !fake) return;

    // Присвоение значение real к fake
    fake.innerHTML = real.innerHTML; };
  // Запуск функции
  innerSwitcher();
});
```